# Laravel Eloquent create method skipping IDs and returning them

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-4

I'm simply trying to create a new model through Eloquent's create method. However, we're seeing that the new model will sometimes contain an id that has been skipped in mysql. This id is designated as an autoincrement column in mysql.

We are also seeing this happen when using DB:getPdo()->lastInsertId() immediately after the model has been created.

```
$questionResponse = $response->questionResponses()->create([
   'survey_question_id' => $question->id,
   'response' => 5
]);

$response_id = $questionResponse->id; // weve also used DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

Queue::push('TheWorker', array('survey_id' => $survey->id, 'response_id' => $response_id, 'question_id' => $question->id, 'user_id' => $user->id, 'student_target_id' => $student_target_id));
```

TheWorker then fails due to receiving an incorrect $repsonse_id that doesn't exist in the DB.

We would expect that the newly created model would contain the id that matches the record created in mysql.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's the problem? You expect `auto_increment` to always be sequential, as in `1, 2, 3, 4..... 2^32`? It's not doing that. When a query fails (deadlock etc.), those numbers are lost. They're not reused. There's a very, very strong reason for that. It's not a problem because `auto_increment` is there to provide **unique** value, not **sequential** value. It just uses a sequential algorithm to get that unique value. You can try to get those numbers to be sequential, but you'll be opening Pandora's box and running into so many problems down the line that you'll want to quit your job.

Comment: @mjh Thanks for taking a look. The problem we're having is that the $questionResponse is being created but getting returned with the wrong id. For example, it may get returned with an id of 356890, but there is no record with this id in the DB. However, the record is still being created, but with an id akin to 356950, and all records with ids from 356890 to 356949 are non-existent.

Comment: That appears to be an entirely different issue. If an eloquent model is returned and contains an `id` with non-null value - that means the database created it. Now, why it's gone - we don't have access to your code. Are you using transactions? Are there any triggers on the database? There's way too many questions to figure what's going on, but one thing is for sure: an `auto_increment` doesn't re-use values that have been lost and forcing it to do so won't fix your problem.

Comment: We aren't using transactions and there are no triggers on the DB. I'm sorry if I may have miscommunicated, but we are fine with the skipped id values being skipped. All were trying to do is get the correct id for the record that was actually created. I'll add a little more to the post to show what were trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'd also like to add that this is happening very sporadically, so we may be looking at some sort of race condition, but I'm still not sure what kind of condition would result in this issue.

Comment: I see that you're creating a `$questionResponse` and it's referencing `survey_question_id`. Is `$question` also being created or is it simply loaded? If there are two queries that create/update/delete, use a transaction. If  you're using `InnoDB` storage engine, check the output of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` - you might find more info related to potential race conditions and deadlocks. I must admit that it does seem very odd, you do get `id` populated in the Eloquent model which indicates MySQL did succeed with the insert..

Comment: @Mjh Thanks for your insight! You mentioning that the id populates if the insert succeeds pointed me in the right direction. Turns out there was some code that I was unaware of that deleted questionsReponses if a race condition was met.

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad you got nudged in the right direction! :)